# Regex: split to the last occurence of path

Tags: c++, regex, path, filepath, unc

I want to split up an UNC-path for hostname, shared folder, path, filename and extension. I almost got it, but the last sequence is somehow wrong because I didn't get the filenaem correctly.

e.g.

```
//host/shared/path1/path2/path3/filename.pdf
```

should be split up to:

```
host
shared
path1/path2/path3
filename
pdf
```

But at the moment I get something like this:

```
host
shared
path1/path2/path3/filenam
e
pdf
```

using this regex:

```
std::regex rgx("\/\/(\\w+?){1,1}\/(\\w+?)\/([\\w\/]+)([^\\.])\\.(.+)$");
```

So what is wrong with it and how can I solve it?

Comment: Replace `\/` with `/`. And use `R"()"` notation so as not to double escape `\w`. `{1,1}` can be removed, it is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove the group "([^\\.])" as the following "\\." matches the period at the end. You also want another word group to match the file name itself that is followed by the period like so:

```
std::regex rgx("\/\/(\\w+?){1,1}\/(\\w+?)\/([\\w\/]+)\/([\\w]+)\\.(.+)$");
```

https://regex101.com/r/yK4zH1/4